# EACCES, permission denied; You don't have access to this file

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, meanjs, yo

> $ yo meanjs
>
> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/pain/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'
>
> You don't have access to this file.

[image]

What is it? What I must doing?

Answer (score -3):

Verify you have all the requirements properly installed and updated:

```
$ sudo npm install -g yo
$ sudo npm install -g generator-meanjs
```

If that doesn't work, please post the entire error message —in text, not screengrab.

Comment: Encourage people to use https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions instead.

Comment: @chachan Why not actually post an answer so future visitors can benefit?

Comment: I'm sorry @BryanH, I don't have the answer to the specific question. I do know that installing packages through sudo should be avoided as possible. The link I posted explains how to do it the right way. Hope that helps